# Select only one number in multiple value in column

Tags: php, mysql

http://imageshack.com/a/img43/3586/p49t.jpg

i have select only 11 number in user_assign column.
so how to write MySQL query in PHP ...
Thanks

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('11', user_assign);
```

Comment: You are welcome man, if you feel answer was correct don't forget to accept it, so you will also help people in the future with similar problems.

Comment: soory dude but not run query please give me a example my question:)

Comment: What do you mean? Did you replace `table` with your actual table name?

Comment: yup dude .. you see http://imageshack.com/a/img43/3586/p49t.jpg and select only 11 number in user_assign colume

Comment: I can't see table name here, what's the problem?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM task WHERE FIND_IN_SET('11', user_assign);`